# WPF: How to apply a simple animation to a Label?

Tags: wpf, animation, triggers, label

I have a label with an image inside. I'd like to apply a simple animation: changing the opacity property for achieving a fade-in effect after the label is loaded (or when is visible or whatever)

But this doesn't work:

```
<Label ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource ImageLabelDataTemplate}"  Canvas.Left="36" Canvas.Top="394" Height="116" Name="PreviousVirtualButton" Width="100" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:5" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>                            
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
```

I'd like to see how the label is fading in on the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably start to accept answers to some of your questions.  It gives you points toward your reputation and it also gives more incentive for others to answer your questions since they also get points if you accept their answers. =)

Comment: Please accept a reply as answer if it solves your problem. It gives encouragement to others to answer too.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUnleashed.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" Width="200" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="300" MaxHeight="120" MinHeight="120" Height="120">
    <Grid>
        <Label Canvas.Left="36" Content="HELLO" Canvas.Top="394" Height="116" Name="PreviousVirtualButton" Width="100">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `Visibility="Hidden"`, it will work (assuming you want it to fade in when it loads). Otherwise, set the `Visibility` to `Visibility.Visible` from code-behind when you want it to start fade in. Also, make sure that in the ContentTemplate you have something visible.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the label visible in your code somewhere?  You have to set it to be visible in order for the animation to trigger.

C# example:
 
    previousVirtualButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;